# How can I exclude some packages from (transitive) dependencies?

Tags: maven, dependency-tree

I depend on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test` which depends on `org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:test`.

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.33:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:test
```

Now in my test clases, there are two candidates for statically importing `assertNotNull`.

One is

`import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;`

And the other is

`import static org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Contracts.assertNotNull;`

Is there any nice way to exclude the hibernate one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only exclude whole dependencies, not parts of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```